# Resizing the ImageView According to the aspect Ratio of Images of non specific aspect ratio of image

Tags: android, user-interface

I want make make Ui like following where the imageview is of differernt sizes in the recycler view
[image: Sample Required UI]

what i did is i made the Imageview(inside the recycler view) to wrap content but the image view , i dont understant if it is grid view becuase of varible number of columns

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ImageViewer"
        android:id="@+id/imageviewerLayout"

        >
        <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageviewer"
         />

        <!--<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="58dp"-->

        <!--/>-->
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab1"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_downward_black_24dp"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab3"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_share_black_24dp"
        />


       </LinearLayout>




      </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout#flexboxlayoutmanager-within-recyclerview can do the job for you

Answer (score 2):

I think it's the FlexboxLayoutManager what you're looking for: https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout#flexboxlayoutmanager-within-recyclerview

If it doesn't work for you, you can try with SpanSizeLookup, but it will be much harder than implementing the FlexboxLayoutManager:

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup

Comment: it have a lot of option and not clear answer to get the layout what they show as an example

Comment: You have the example with gallery in the repository: https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout/tree/master/demo-cat-gallery

Comment: i cant seem to get it work as given in example i have used 3 attributes layoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);
        
        layoutManager.setFlexWrap(FlexWrap.WRAP);
        layoutManager.setAlignItems(AlignItems.STRETCH);  but the recycler view shows a single column, and is there specific changes required to single item xml ? becuase i have set it to wrap content

Comment: Have you checked the item.xml in the example? How it is structured? Or have you run the example to see if it is what you're looking for?

Comment: only thing that i noticed important about layout is the use of Coordinate layout , should that make a differernce?